# vscode の codeコマンド で ワイルドカードのようなものを使用して現在のウィンドウの上で複数ファイルを開きたい

Tags: vscode, powershell

## やりたいこと

vscodeの"code"コマンドでファイル指定をする際にワイルドカードを使用したい。

## 問題

例えば、"filename_001","filename_002"という二つのファイルがカレントディレクトリにある場合

```
> code filename_001 filename_002
```

としないといけない。めんどくさい
もし、ワイルドカードを使用できれば上のコマンドは

```
> code filename*
```

で実行できるのに！
しかし、これをすると新しいウィンドウが開いてしまう。
なので解決策は考えてみたもののこれだとやりたいことができていないことになる。

## 実行環境

windows11
powershell

```
> # powershellのバージョン
> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.2.7
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.2.7
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
> # vscodeのバージョン
> code --version      
1.74.0
5235c6bb189b60b01b1f49062f4ffa42384f8c91
x64
```

教えてほしいこと

vscodeの"code"コマンドでワイルドカードを指定してファイルを開くためのコマンド。

Comment: いったん検討リストに入ったけど実現されなかったようです。[Open multiple files at once from the command line using wildcards #80891](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80891) もしかしたらこんな拡張機能で代替できるかもしれませんね。[Open Matching Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bcanzanella.openmatchingfiles)

Comment: ちなみにワイルドカード指定をPowerShellのスクリプトで処理して、その結果を使って間接的にVSCodeを起動するラッパーを作るというなら、こちらの機能が使えるのでは？ [about_Wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: ありがとうございました。公式で実装されていないのですね。
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.3
を使うと新しくウィンドウが開いてしまいます。
vscodeを起動するのではなく、vscodeを開いた状態で複数ファイルをシェル上から開きたいということです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ここでVS codeの[実行パラメータ](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line)を使うのが重要なポイントになります。このパラメータを使えば複数のファイルを同じウィンドウで開くようになります： `-r --reuse-window`
このように使用できます：

```
code.exe --reuse-window filename_001 filename_002
```

簡単な[Powershell関数](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.3)を作ればもっと使いやすくなります。例えば：

```
function launchcode{
    if($null -eq $Args){
            code.exe
        } else {
            code.exe --reuse-window @args
        }
}
```

もちろん関数の名前は自由に変えても構わないです。上記の関数はこのように実行できます：

```
launchcode filename_001
launchcode filename_003 filename_004
```

繰り返して実行しても同じウィンドウで開きます。試したところ、ワイルドカードでもOKです：

```
launchcode filename_00*
```